# MacOs 12.5 - Unable to Create /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist

Tags: macos, macos-monterey

I am trying to create the file as below and providing my password but the file is not created, can someone please help me with this issue?

`sudo touch /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist`

Answer (score 0):

The System is immutable since Big Sur.
Try putting it in ~/Library instead.